Keeping ainput prompt as last console line
(python >= 3.7)
I'm currently writing a library that extends functionality for guilded.py (discord.py-esque library) to the console.
One problem I'm currently having is keeping the prompt as the last line of stdout.
    async def _on_console(self):
        """
        Console starts listening for inputs using aioconsole ainputs.
        """
        logger.info("Console is ready and is listening for commands\n")
        
        while True:
            if self.console_stop_flag:
                self.console_stop_flag = False
                logger.info("Console was stopped and is no longer listening for commands\n")
                break
            try:
                # Get input from the user
                console_in = (await ainput(self.prompt)).strip() # from aioconsole import ainput, self.prompt defaults to "> "
                
                if len(console_in) == 0:
                    continue
                self.dispatch("console_message", console_in)
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()

This works fine until something gets written to stdout, whether it's a print statement or an Exception.
# | represents where the cursor is
# Before Written
Logged in as Console Bot
> |

# Assuming we have a "hi" command defined that prints ("hi" command ran) whenever it's run.
# After Written
Logged in as Console Bot
> "hi" command ran.
|

How can I make it stick to the bottom of the console? (When new messages are written to stdout, I want it to be printed ABOVE the prompt)
# | represents where the cursor is
# Before Written
Logged in as Console Bot
> |

# Assuming we have a "hi" command defined that prints ("hi" command ran) whenever it's run.
# After Written
Logged in as Console Bot
"hi" command ran.
> |

I tried overwriting sys.stdout (although this is probably not the best solution), and this didn't work either.
class ConsoleOutputWrapper:
    def __init__(self, original_stdout, prompt):
        self.original_stdout = original_stdout
        self.prompt = prompt

    def write(self, message):
        # Clear the current line and move to the beginning
        self.original_stdout.write('\033[K') # also tried using '\x1b[1K\r'
        self.original_stdout.write(message)
        self.original_stdout.write('\n' + self.prompt)
        self.original_stdout.flush()

    def flush(self):
        self.original_stdout.flush()

sys.stdout = ConsoleOutputWrapper() # with arguments

Results had a lot of newlines and random prompts everywhere.
Logged in as Console Bot
>

> test
>
Received console message: test



>

EDIT:
I would also like to keep the actual written input on the bottom line.
If something is written to stdout while I am typing, it gets written directly after what I've written and it makes it a mess to read.
Logged in as Console Bot

> I am writ"hi" command was ran.
ing

